# Proving that tensor distributes over biproduct in an additive monoidal category

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, category-theory, monoidal-categories

I'm trying to prove that the tensor product distributes over biproducts in an additive monoidal category; namely that given objects $A,B,C$, we have $A \otimes (B \oplus C) \cong (A \otimes B) \oplus (A \otimes C)$.  What I've attempted is:

[image: picture]

Now it's clear that the arrows from $A\otimes B$ to $A \otimes B$ collapse to $\mathrm{id}_{A\otimes B}$ and similarly for $A\otimes C$.  I now want to show that $\varphi\circ\theta$ is $\mathrm{id}_{(A\otimes B)\oplus(A\otimes C)}$.  I want to invoke the uniqueness of the (co)product again but this requires a map from $(A\otimes B)$ and $(A\otimes C)$ from the bottom of the diagram up to $(A\otimes B)\oplus(A\otimes C)$ at the top.

I'd *like* to conclude that $p_{A\otimes B}\circ(\varphi\circ\mathrm{id}_A\otimes i_B)  = \mathrm{id}_{A\otimes B}$ implies that $(\varphi\circ\mathrm{id}_A\otimes i_B)=i_{A\otimes B}$.  This intuitively makes sense if considering a concrete example like modules or sets but seems unjustified here.  (Attempting to complete the product diagram with the diagonal composite leads to the problem that it is not a zero morphism... it is $\mathrm{id}_A \otimes 0_{bc}$.)

I found a similar proof in the setting of modules (http://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2007/04/17/more-on-tensor-products-and-direct-sums/) but unfortunately he glosses over the part where I am stuck.  At least I seem to be considering the right morphisms though.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I've been agonizing over this for many hours... does anyone know what to do here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's the definition of an additive monoidal category? Is it that tensor product distributes over addition of morphisms? If so, use the fact that a functor between additive categories preserves addition of morphisms iff it preserves biproducts (see for example [this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/a-meditation-on-semiadditive-categories/)).

Comment: What I mean is a monoidal category $(C, \otimes)$ where the category C is an additive category; (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_category).  I believe the only property I actually need from that definition is that products and coproducts exist for any two objects, and they are always biproducts (which I denoted in my post by $\oplus$).  I'll check out that blog post though and see if there's any ideas there that help.

Comment: @Omnivium: so you don't require any compatibility between the additive and tensor structures? Then there's no reason for biproducts to be preserved. I'm reasonably certain the correct definition is that tensor product distributes over addition of morphisms.

Comment: @Omnivium: for a simple counterexample, take the category of vector spaces and let $\otimes$ be the direct sum.

Comment: I agree 100% with Qiaochu here.

Comment: Haha crap, I think I even thought of a similar counterexample and dismissed it... I guess I desperately wanted it to be true for an easy proof that the multiplication $[A]\cdot[B]=[A\otimes B]$ is well defined on the split Grothendieck group (ring) of the additive category in question.  Guess it's back to the drawing board.  In any case, thanks very much for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

As Qiaochu Yuan pointed out, in a monoidal category with finite biproducts, $\otimes$ doesn't always distribute over $\oplus$. If the functor $X \otimes \_\,$ has a right adjoint for every object $X$, however, then distributivity does hold (see Example 2.4.2 of Chris Heunen's thesis, *Categorical Quantum Models and Logics*). I don't know if this is helpful in your case, but it's pretty cool.

Unfortunately, the fact above doesn't seem to be proven in Heunen's thesis, and the proof isn't obvious to me. I've community-wiki'd this answer so that anyone who knows the proof can add it.

Comment: The proof is trivial: biproducts and binary coproducts coincide in additive categories, and left adjoints preserve all colimits.